# Failed to build Vue project when I use optional chain and set browserslistrc to Electron 12.0.2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I use optional chain and set `Electron 12.0.2` in **.browserslistrc**, the project will failed to build.

```
 in ./src/views/reader/reader.ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:29)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     if (imgElement.length > 0) {
|         console.log('imgElement', imgElement);
>         return imgElement[0]?.classList;
|     }
|     return null;

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-1!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/reader/reader-container.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&setup=true 4:0-43 121:12-27
 @ ./src/views/reader/reader-container.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&setup=true
 @ ./src/views/reader/reader-container.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-1!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/reader.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/reader.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/reader.vue
 @ ./src/reader-main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.3:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/reader-main.ts
```

In reader.ts

```
export function getImgFromPoint(container: HTMLDivElement, selector: string) {
  const imgElement = document
    .elementsFromPoint(container.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2, 100)
    .filter((e) => {
      return e.matches(selector);
    });
  if (imgElement.length > 0) {
    console.log('imgElement', imgElement);
    return imgElement[0]?.classList;
  }
  return null;
}
```

When I set `.browserslistrc` to

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
not dead
```

the project can built successfully.

I think some loader can't resolve `?.` syntax, so the building failed.
And when I set `.browserslistrc` to

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
not dead
```

I think babel will transpile the `?.`, so the loader can handle it. While I set `.browserslistrc` to to `Electron 12.0.2`, babel don't transpile it while Electron 12.0.2 support it.
And before build the project when you changed the `.browserslistrc`, you need del `node_modules/.cache` folder. Otherwise the change won't take effect.

Anyone know which loader caused the parse fail and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227

Comment: Thank you, though I still can't solve this, but I have figured out the reason at least. It seems that upgrade to webpack5 could sole this.

Comment: The solutions are described directly in the issue....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not caused by any loader but directly by Webpack 4.x (the [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227) - Webpack is using old version of Acorn library (to parse the code) which does not work with optional chaining or null coalescing syntax)

If you are **not using** Vue CLI you can upgrade to Webpack 5 to solve this. If you are using Vue CLI, upgrading to Webpack 5 "by hand" is not an option. You must [upgrade](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html#breaking-changes) to Vue CLI 5 (which is currently in the beta)

If you want (or have) to stay on Webpack 4, you have two options:

1. Configure Babel to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` and `@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator` plugins

```js
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator', 
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'
  ],
}
```

2. If you are using TypeScript, do not upgrade to version 3.8 or set compiler option `target` to `es2019`

Comment: You are right, but it seems can't slove my problem, because the framework I used。

Comment: Why is that if I may ask?

Comment: At first, it seems `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` that I used to build my project didn't support vue-cli-5 yet. And I didn't use babel because I use Electron. And I don't want to change `target` to es2019. I would rather give up use optional-chaining.