# Vue CLI compiling vagmi library fails with 'Unexpected token'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite

I am having an issue compiling the vagmi Vue library in the Vue CLI. It works with Vite but when I try to use Vue CLI, which I have to use for his project, it errors:

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                        8:44:29 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/vagmi/dist/index.mjs

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (149:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       config = {
|         chainId: getMaybeRefValue(chainId2),
>         connector: connector_ ?? getMaybeRefValue(connector)
|       };
|     } else {

 @ ./src/main.js 38:0-50 40:13-25 44:57-68
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.228:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I do not know if it is an issue with my Vue CLI setup or a problem with the Vagmi library. I reported it  issue: https://github.com/wobsoriano/vagmi/issues/36 but I don't see anyone else having the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892722/failed-to-build-vue-project-when-i-use-optional-chain-and-set-browserslistrc-to

Comment: Yeah same underlying problem, ty. I'm trying something and will close if same.

Comment: Yeah. Fixed by https://next.cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html