why I can import a UMD in vuecli4.x
when i import in another project with vuecli5,lt's ok to run
but when i import in this one,it's failed
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                             17:31:01

 error  in ./node_modules/smart-editor-v2/lib/smart-editor-v2.umd.min.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9700)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

i want it's compile success

Because it uses JS feature that didn't exist at the time when 4.x was created, like optional chaining. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892722/failed-to-build-vue-project-when-i-use-optional-chain-and-set-browserslistrc-to for example
